# Smart Home - Correct JSON to respond to EXECUTE when device is offline

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

When i try to execute a command and that the device is offline, Assistant still tell me that the command as been successfully be done.

I don't have this problem when it's a QUERY request, but with EXECUTE...

This is my returned JSON:

```
{
  "requestId": "XXXXXX",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "ids": [123],
        "status": "ERROR",
        "errorCode": "deviceTurnedOff",
        "online": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have also try this:

```
{
  "requestId": "XXXXXX",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "ids": [123],
        "status": "OFFLINE",
        "errorCode": "deviceTurnedOff",
        "online": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I expect that when i try to do a command on an offline device, google assistant tell me that the device is not available, but i have a `Ok, i turn the light on` instead.

So if you have any idea, because i have checked my JSON response 1 million times and read the documentation many times but i can't find my mistake.

Comment: Voting to close as I am really not sure what you are asking... If those are your response messages, they clearly state that the device is offline... What do you (expect) to see here?

Comment: @MattClark, I expect the google assistant tell my that the action can't be done, in documentation they say, if the device is offline assistant will tell you that the device is unavailable: _Return the offline state for offline devices. We return 'not available right now' as TTS for this error._

Comment: Try returning your device ids as strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/reference/errors-exceptions) is a bit confusing because the example shows the response payload for the QUERY intent.

The response payload for an EXECUTE intent is slightly different and is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/process-intents#EXECUTE).

The JSON using the correct reference the EXECUTE response payload will look like:

```
{
  "requestId": "XXXXXX",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [{
      "ids": ["123"],
      "status": "OFFLINE",
      "errorCode": "deviceTurnedOff"
    }]
  }
}
```

Note: deviceId should be a string, as noted in the EXECUTE Response payload details.

Quoting from the doc:

> ids: Array. Required. Partner device IDs of the response